# $\sum_{k=1}^{m+n} \binom {m+n}k k^m (-1)^k=0 , \forall m,n\in \mathbb N$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Is it true that  $\sum_{k=1}^{m+n} \binom {m+n}k k^m (-1)^k=0 , \forall m,n\in \mathbb N$ ?

I feel that it is true because if we define $H_1 (x,r)=rx(1+x)^{r-1}$ , and

$H_{m+1}(x,r)=x \dfrac d {dx} {H_m (x,r)}$ , then  $H_m (x,r)=\sum_{k=1}^{r} \binom {r}k k^m x^k$ and I have noticed , for first few $m$

that we can write $H_m (x,r)=\sum_{i=1}^m f(x,r,i)(1+x)^{r-i}$ , for some function $f$ so I thought that if I

let $r>m$ , then I should have $H_m (-1,r)=0$ i.e. $H_m (-1,m+n)=0$ ,(since $m+n>n$) but I am not totally sure  .

Note:- $ 0\notin \mathbb N$

Comment: For you, does $0\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Julien: No , $0 \notin \mathbb N$

Answer (score 3):

We must be assuming that $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$ since this is false for $m+n=1$.

Since $m\gt0$, this is the same as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\binom{m+n}{k}k^m(-1)^k=0\tag{1}
$$
which is the $m+n$ order forward difference of the function $k^m$. Each forward difference decreases the degree of a polynomial by one. Since the order is greater than the degree, the forward difference is $0$.

Note that we can write any polynomial as a linear combination of combinatorial polynomials of the same degree and lower. To be precise,
$$
\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}
k^m=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{k}{j}\,\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\tag{2}
$$
where $\stirtwo{m}{j}$ is a [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m+n}{k}\binom{k}{j}\,\stirtwo{m}{j}j!(-1)^k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}(-1)^k\binom{m+n}{k}\binom{k}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}(-1)^k\binom{m+n}{j}\binom{m+n-j}{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\binom{m+n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{m+n-j}(-1)^{k+j}\binom{m+n-j}{k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\stirtwo{m}{j}j!\binom{m+n}{j}(-1)^j(1-1)^{m+n-j}\\
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
since $m+n-j\ge n\gt0$ in all terms of the sum.

Comment: No , $ 0 \notin \mathbb N$

Comment: @SouvikDey: yes, that is what I concluded (and I prefer). I just wanted to make that explicit since "[There is no universal agreement about whether to include zero in the set of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number)".

Comment: robjohn: True , and I like your method.

Comment: Perhaps this remark was for my comment..I had never heard about Stirling Number. Nice approach. (+1).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{m + n}{m + n \choose k}k^{m}\pars{-1}^{k} = 0:\ {\Large ?}
     \,,\quad\forall\ m,n\ \in\ \mathbb N}$

> $$
> \pars{1 - z}^{m + n}=\sum_{k = 1}^{m + n}{m + n \choose k}z^{k}\pars{-1}^{k}
> $$

$$
\pars{z\,\partiald{}{z}}^{m}\pars{1 - z}^{m + n}
=\sum_{k = 1}^{m + n}{m + n \choose k}k^{m}z^{k}\pars{-1}^{k}
$$

> $$
> \!\!\!\!\!\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{m + n}{m + n \choose k}k^{m}\pars{-1}^{k}}
> =\lim_{z \to 1^{-}}\bracks{\pars{z\,\partiald{}{z}}^{m}\pars{1 - z}^{m + n}}
> =\lim_{z \to 0^{-}}\partiald[m]{\bracks{\pars{1 - \expo{z}}^{m + n}}}{z}
> =\color{#00f}{\large 0}
> $$